# Deriving function name

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i want to get the simple function name from the acceptsearchmatch method.For ex- say the match occurs in a fun foo(),how can i retreive just foo from match object?help
thanks

Comment: say what?! Can you elaborate please?

Comment: what does searchMatch.getElement return for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at the [same method in `RefactoringSearchEngine2` class](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/RefactoringSearchEngine2.java.htm#ixzz0eShu5Sl4), could you do something similar, in order to check if it is a IMethod, and, if it is, get its name?

```
public final void acceptSearchMatch(final SearchMatch  match) throws CoreException  {
  final SearchMatch accepted= fRequestor.acceptSearchMatch(match);
  if (accepted != null) {
    fCollectedMatches.add(accepted);
    final IResource resource= accepted.getResource();
    if (!resource.equals(fLastResource)) {
      if (fBinary) {
        final IJavaElement element= JavaCore.create(resource);
```

For a [`IJavaElement`](http://www.jdocs.com/eclipse/3.2/api-index.html?m=class&p=org.eclipse.jdt.core&c=IJavaElement&render=classic), you can check if it is a `IMethod`, which should give you access to its name.

```
public String getElementName()
```

> Returns the simple name of this method. For a constructor, this returns the simple name of the declaring type.